Is there hotkey to press "OK"?
Is there hotkey to press "OK" in the "Problem Report" window?
PS: I am looking for some thing like CMD+d, which click "Don't save".

In this particular case shift-tab will suffice. It requires Keyboard Navigation to be enabled in System Settings. There is also built-in keyboard shortcut to toggle the way tab moves: Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard > Change the way Tab moves focus (control+F7)

@AivarPaalberg That is good enough. If you put it into an answer, I can accept it. I will add the screenshot if you don't have it.

I believe you would need to press Tab or use the arrow keys to change the active button so that OK is blue, then press Enter.
To allow the above behavior, enable "Keyboard navigation" in system settings:


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
